# Python Writing Quadratic Formula

Tags: python

I want to try and make my print function automatically substitute the variable 'a' 'b' and 'c' with one of the values assigned to those variables in my tests. How would I do this?
My ideal output would look like this
Equation: 1x**2 + 4x + 4
One root.
2.0

```
import math

def quadraticRoots(a,b,c):
    print('Equation: ax**2 + bx + c')    # (this is what I am trying and it doesn't work)
    discriminant = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    if discriminant > 0:
        root1 = float(-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4 * a * c))/ (2 * a)
        root2 = float(-b - math.sqrt(b**2 - 4 * a * c))/ (2 * a)
        print('Two roots.')
        print(root1)
        print(root2)
    elif discriminant == 0:
        root1 = float(-b + math.sqrt(b**2 - 4 * a * c))/ (2 * a)
        print('One root.')
        print(root1)
    elif discriminant < 0:
        print('No roots.')

def test():
    quadraticRoots(1,0,0)
    quadraticRoots(2,-11,-21)
    quadraticRoots(4,1,4)
    quadraticRoots(1,2,8)
    quadraticRoots(3,-11,19)
    quadraticRoots(1,4,4)
    quadraticRoots(16,-11,64)
    quadraticRoots(1,18,81)
    quadraticRoots(1,7,42)
    quadraticRoots(5,10,5)

test()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
print('Equation: {0}x**2 + {1}x + {2}'.format(a,b,c))
```

Comment: Note that when you're accessing positional arguments in order, you can omit the numbers from your format string, and just use `{}`s. You only need the numbers if you're doing something complicated, like repeating them or using them in a different order than the arguments are provided.

Comment: Today I've learned. I didn't know that you can use `{}` only :)

Comment: Me too, did not know that. +1 to Blckknght's comment for teaching something cool :)

Comment: `{0:2.1}`. The `2` is the total number of digits while the `1` is the number of decimal digits (precision).

Comment: You can also use keyword instead of positional arguments to format `print('Equation: {a}x**2 + {b}x + {c}'.format(a=a, b=b, c=c))`, which looks pretty close to the original equation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you stating that

```
 print('Equation: ax**2 + bx + c')
```

does not print the equation with values for a , b and c

```
print ('equation: ' + str(a) + 'x**2 + ' + str(b) + 'x + ' + str(c))
```

the problem is that you are asking it to print a literal but you want it to print based on your values.  CAVEAT I think you must be using a 3+ flavor of python and I work in 2.7